# Loading taxonomy term missing the custom field data

Tags: taxonomy-terms

```
  foreach ($tids as $tid) {
200     try{
201       $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
202       if(!empty($term) && !empty($teams_records[$term->name])) {
203         //term objects before update
204         $pre_term_objects_log .= print_r($term, TRUE);
205         $pre_term_objects_log .= "\n";
206         $pre_log_message .= ap_cfb_get_log_msg($term);
207         $term->field_conf_record[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $teams_records[$term->name]['in_conference'];
208         $term->field_overall_record[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $teams_records[$term->name]['overall'];
209         taxonomy_term_save($term);
210         $post_log_message .= ap_cfb_get_log_msg($tid, 1, $post_object_log_file);
211       }
212     }
213     catch(Exception $e){
214       $transaction->rollback();
215       $taxonomy_save_log_file_path = $cfb_files_path.'ap_teams_taxonomy_log.txt';
```

Some associated fields data of the taxonomy term are missing when loading the data using the Drupal functions [taxonomy_term_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7.x) and [taxonomy_term_load_multiple()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load_multiple/7.x), but data exist in the database.

On further investigation, I came to know that the Drupal functions taxonomy_term_load() and taxonomy_term_load_multiple() are not getting the values from database for one of the team/term.

Are there any issues with Drupal core functions fetching the data from cache_tables* ?

Does the above function code have any issues?

Do we need to write custom SQL queries to fetch the term ID?

Comment: taxonomy_term_load() and taxonomy_term_load_multiple() does return custom fields data. Try clearing site cache if that helps. You can also try using [entity_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/entity_load/7.x) function to load term. e.g. `$tid = array(123); $terms = entity_load('taxonomy_term', $tid);`.

Comment: I see, some issues with Entity cache module and the way content is cached in cache_tables. 

Entity_load function is going to behave the same.

Do we have any other way, to it directly node/taxo tables ?

Otherwise, I have to disable entity_cache module and truncate all cache tables and then find out the result

Comment: Rather using taxonomy_term_save function ? any other way to store only these 2 fields  ( do I have to write custom sql queries or node_save)

 $term->field_conf_record[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $teams_records[$term->name]['in_conference'];
208         $term->field_overall_record[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $teams_records[$term->name]['overall'];
209         taxonomy_term_save($term);

@Yogesh --^^

Comment: @Yogesh is right: `taxonomy_term_load()` / `entity_load()` should load all the field data. But if entity_cache is getting in your way, you can clear just for the term you need without incurring a giant performance problem by clearing more caches than needed. See my answer below for details.

Comment: @user3494869 Also note that if you do construct custom queries to pull out the data directly from tables you are aware of, this may be the lightest but most fragile approach, making code difficult to maintain and brittle as new code is added to the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If entity_cache is preventing that, you can call:

`entity_get_controller('taxonomy_term')->resetCache(array($tid));`

directly in your code, to ensure that specific term cache is reset (but without clearing more caches than needed).

Note that without entity_cache, the controller for taxonomy_term is [TaxonomyTermController](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/class/TaxonomyTermController/7.x), but with entity_cache enabled it is [EntityCacheTaxonomyTermController](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21entitycache%21entitycache.taxonomy.inc/class/EntityCacheTaxonomyTermController/7) – so check out how [EntityCacheTaxonomyTermController::resetCache](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21entitycache%21entitycache.taxonomy.inc/function/EntityCacheTaxonomyTermController%3A%3AresetCache/7) works (this is what will be called with the above snippet.

Regarding your question about a custom query: I'm adding my comment above to my answer because it is part of your original questions:

> Also note that if you do construct custom queries to pull out the data
>   directly from tables you are aware of, this may be the lightest but
>   most fragile approach, making code difficult to maintain and brittle
>   as new code is added to the project.